# Automatically download csv file with hidden link

Tags: python, request

I'm trying to write a function that automatically download the table from the link below (when you click Tabelle exportieren->CSV-export button on the right)
https://www.marktstammdatenregister.de/MaStR/Einheit/Einheiten/OeffentlicheEinheitenuebersicht

The thing is, when I checked its HTML code, there is no link for the .csv file (href = '#'), seems like the link was hidden.

Is there any way to search for that hidden link, with some filters applied for the table?

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add data then you may have to use selenium to control web browser which runs JavaScript. If you need to download only this file then you can get url after downloading in browser (in download manage should be option "get url of downloaded element") and then you can use this url in your code.

Comment: it's something like this: blob:url/d158690c-25bb-4c32-824a-c4107b7cb249. Seems like an arbitrary query...

Comment: it seems it doesn't generate CSV on sever but in browser using JavaScript. You will have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser and click this link - and browser will download it.

Answer (score 1):

The website is loading the data dynamically, i.e. there is a server at the backend which is populating the result, for this you need to use selenium package and then capture the html.